# sqlx + Go: Output parameter in stored procedure

Tags: go, sqlx

I have mssql stored procedure that contains output parameter and can be called like this

```
EXEC [SP_NAME]
    @Input = N'Some Text',
    @Result = @Result OUTPUT
```

Do you know if it's possible to access this `@Result` in **jmoiron/sqlx** after sp call?

Comment: Seems you can't do it currently in this package. Btw, it's better to address this kind of questions on package's GH page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sqlx` is just a wrapper around `database/sql` package. The query you're trying to perform is driver specific. Thus, it depends on the driver you're using to connect to the MSSQL server. If you're using https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb, based on [issue #78](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/78), you can try the following:

```
rows, err := db.Queryx(`EXEC [SP_NAME] @Input, @Result OUTPUT; 
          SELECT Result = @Result;`, sql.Named("Input", "Some Text"))
//do something with rows...
```

Comment: weird I get `sql: expected 0 arguments, got 1`

Comment: @ilpaijin, Following the [issue #78](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/78), OUTPUT param is supported now. For more detail, see [issue #318](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/318)